# Unique Constraint check

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I just want to set trigger for unique constraint that check data already exists or not and it is not working..kindly help me out

```
DECLARE
   V   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (*)
     INTO V
     FROM AR_RECEIPTS
    WHERE BANK_INSTRUMENT_NO = :BANK_INSTRUMENT;
   IF V= 0
   THEN
      MESSAGE ('Instrument Number Already Exists!');
      MESSAGE ('Instrument Number Already Exists!');
      RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE;
   END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Is it a trigger? can you please share whole code of the trigger?

Comment: You can set a constraint at table level rather than creating a trigger on table.

Comment: @Tejash yes sir it is trigger and whole code is shared..

Comment: @XING Sir I already set it at database level...it was error on form level and now error is fixed

Comment: It's a while since I last used Forms, but I recall that it was worth defining separate alerts for information, warning and error messages. Popping up an informational message twice then raising `FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE` seems like a hack.

Comment: 1.Do you already have a unique(or primary) constraint on `bank_instrument_no` column ?                   2.Do you want to show up the message during the insert?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show the message when the user is attempting to insert a duplicate BANK_INSTRUMENT your test should be `IF V > 0`. At the moment you show the message when that instrument number **does not exist** in the target table.

Please be aware that while this check may seem user-friendly - checking and informing the user in the UI rather than getting an exception from the database - it is not safe. In a multi-user environments two users may enter the same number, get the all clear and submit duplicates. You still need to enforce the unique constraint in the database:

```
alter table ar_receipts add constraint ar_receipts_uk unique (bank_instrument_no);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is correct now it is fine working according to requirement...

```
DECLARE
   V   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (*)
     INTO V
     FROM AR_RECEIPTS
    WHERE BANK_INSTRUMENT_NO = :BANK_INSTRUMENT;

   IF V<>'0'
   THEN
      MESSAGE ('Instrument Number Already Exists!');
      MESSAGE ('Instrument Number Already Exists!');
      RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE;
   END IF;
END;
```

Comment: `v` is a number, so you should compare it to `0`, not `'0'`. (I'm not sure I understand the logic anyway - if `:BANK_INSTRUMENT` does not exist in `AR_RECEIPTS` then you raise an error saying it already exists. Is that correct?)

Answer (score 0):

If this is a trigger, I would expect that `WHERE BANK_INSTRUMENT_NO = :BANK_INSTRUMENT;`
should be replaced with something like `WHERE BANK_INSTRUMENT_NO = :NEW.BANK_INSTRUMENT;`

It would be easier if the entire trigger was provided.

Comment: it is whole trigger code and now it is done..thank you